# Add content file in ClickOnce Publish

Tags: msbuild, clickonce, publish, data-files

I have an excel template which I would like to add as part of ClickOnce publish.

When I add the excel as a link to the ClickOnce project and publish, it is added as .xlsx.deploy and removing it from Application Folder to the root publish folder throws error.

Is there a way to add a content file to the ClickOnce publish and not include in the set up ?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Do you want the Excel sheet to be deployed with your application or not?

Comment: Is there a way to add the excel template to ClickOnce publish as a data file, without it getting deployed with .deploy extension and a reference in dll.manifest ?

Comment: The .deploy extension is added automatically and will be removed on the client machine, so you should not have to worry about it.